# Update LastModifiedDate field of custom object

Tags: javascript, custom-object, field-update

I'm uploading attachments to a custom object using the following JS.
I want to update the LastModifiedDate field of the custom object each time I do this.
Would anyone have any suggestions as to how I might accomplish this?

My initial attempt in the onSuccess function below does not work...

```
function uploadFile(customObj)
{       
var input = document.getElementById('file-input');
var parentId = customObj.Id

var filesToUpload = input.files;

for(var i = 0, f; f = filesToUpload[i]; i++)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();     

    // Keep a reference to the File in the FileReader so it can be accessed in callbacks
    reader.file = f; 

    reader.onerror = function(e) 
    {
        switch(e.target.error.code) 
        {
            case e.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                alert('File Not Found!');
                break;
            case e.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
                alert('File is not readable');
                break;
            case e.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
                break; // noop
            default:
                alert('An error occurred reading this file.');
        };
    };     

    reader.onabort = function(e) 
    {
        alert('File read cancelled');
    };

    reader.onload = function(e) 
    {
        var att = new sforce.SObject("Attachment");
        att.Name = this.file.name;
        att.ContentType = this.file.type;
        att.ParentId = parentId;

        att.Body = (new sforce.Base64Binary(e.target.result)).toString();

        sforce.connection.create([att],
        {
            onSuccess : function(result, source) 
            {
                if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) 
                {
                  var test_date = customObj;              <-- POSSIBLE SOLUTION?
                  test_date.LastModifiedDate = new Date();<-- POSSIBLE SOLUTION?                     
                  sforce.connection.update([test_date ]); <-- POSSIBLE SOLUTION?  

                   console.log("new attachment created with id " + result[0].id);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    console.log("failed to create attachment " + result[0]);
                }
            }, 
            onFailure : function(error, source) 
            {
                console.log("An error has occurred " + error);
            }
        });
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just "touch" the record with an update that doesn't change anything. Similar to how user would hit Edit and then Save without changing anything on the page.

This will cause all workflows, validation rules etc to run of course!

Something like this should be enough:

```
var parent = new sforce.SObject("Account");
parent.id = customObj.Id;
result = sforce.connection.update([parent]);
```

(even better if the object you're passing to the function already is created with this library and not some totally separate data structure you've made that has pretty much only the `id` attribute)

Having said that... maybe you should have this bit of logic in a trigger and not Javascript? Should it work only for these uploads or anytime an attachment is added to your custom object?

Comment: Thanks for the response eyescream, and I think you're right, it should work whenever someone adds an attachment and not just through this particular script...

Comment: But at the same time, I would really like to get this approach to work. At the moment I'm getting the following error when using your approach:

An error has occurred {faultcode:'sf:INVALID_TYPE', faultstring:'INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'Answer__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name.

Answer__c is my custom object, should I handle this differently to a standard object?

Comment: Should work the same. Might be something to do with Profile. Do you have read & edit rights to the object and is the tab not marked as hidden? Is it really your object or is it a part of managed package (needs to be `namespace__Answer__c` in that case)?

Comment: I don't think it's a read/write issue, and I have some code which attaches the correct prefix... very frustrating.

Comment: I'm pretty sure updating of custom objects is no different. Experiment with other custom object & different (valid) Id? Any chances you have a typo in the object's API name? :D Try something hardcoded: `var p = new sforce.SObject("ns__Answer__c");
p.id = '0a1.....';
result = sforce.connection.update([p]);` What's the API version of the "connection.js" you're using, maybe bump it up? If it's a fairly new object in that managed package - it might be invisible to the programs that use old API version...

Comment: No, the API name is correct so hardcoding an Id produces the same result. And this particular object is quite old so I don't think it's am issue with connection.js either. Really appreciate the suggestions!

Comment: And suddenly it's working! Maybe there was a typo I corrected somewhere while working on you're suggestion?? Anyway, you're idea worked! Much appreciated!